# Android API Calendar

Tags: android, api, calendar

I am creating an android app with the android 4.1 API, and I have an issue with it.

I seem to have a problem with my code compiling, while it does not give me any errors, it does crash when I try to run it on the Android Phone.

```
package com.example.meetingmute;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Calendars;
import android.provider.CalendarContract.Events;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.media.AudioManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
TextView text;
boolean ringeronoff;
AudioManager mAudioManager;
AlertDialog ad;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    ContentResolver contentResolver =       getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

    final Cursor cursor =  contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"),
            (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }), null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        final String _id = cursor.getString(0);
        final String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
        final Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");

        System.out.println("Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);
    }
    ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    read();

    Cursor cur = null;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

//Submit the query and get a Cursor object back. 
cur = cr.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ringeronoff == true){
                text.setText("Ringer is On");
                mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                ringeronoff = false;
            }
            else{
                text.setText("Ringer is Off");
                mAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                ringeronoff = true;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: Post your logcat. How else are we suppose to have any idea what part is crashing. Its one of the most important things when diagnosing a crash. Make it a habbit.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this is wrong and will not work on Android 4.1:

```
final Cursor cursor =  contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"),
        (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }), null, null, null);
```

Simply put, if you intend on using the calendar API you should use the `CalendarContract`and subclasses and refrain from hard-coding constants into your code like this.

For instance, the URI you are using - `content://calendar/calendars` - contains the authority `calendar` - it should be `com.android.calendar` - or even better, just pass the [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html#CONTENT_URI) from the API.